# Remove characters from a specific index character

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring

I would like to know how can i remove characters in a string from a specific index like :

```
string str = "this/is/an/example"
```

I want to remove all characters from the third '/' including so it would be like this:

```
str = "this/is/an"
```

I tried with substring and regex but i cant find a solution.

Comment: `var newStr = str.Remove(str.LastIndexOf('/'));`

Comment: @Habib make that an answer and I'll vote for it.

Comment: @Habib: That assumes that there are only three slashes in the string.

Comment: @Guffa, right. But this *very simple*  code should :P `var newStr2 = str.Remove(str.Select((r, i) => new { Value = r, Index = i }).Where(r => r.Value == '/').Skip(2).Take(1).Select(pos => pos.Index).FirstOrDefault());` Just the issue is, if the character is not found, it will return an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get "this/is/an":

```
string str = "this/is/an/example";
string new_string = str.Remove(str.LastIndexOf('/'));
```

If you need to keep the slash:

```
string str = "this/is/an/example";
string new_string = str.Remove(str.LastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

This expects there to be at least one slash. If none are present, you should check it beforehand to not throw an exception:

```
string str = "this.s.an.example";
string newStr = str;
if (str.Contains('/'))
    newStr = str.Remove(str.LastIndexOf('/'));
```

If its importaint to get the third one, make a dynamic method for it, like this. Input the string, and which "folder" you want returned. 3 in your example will return "this/is/an":

```
    static string ReturnNdir(string sDir, int n)
    {
        while (sDir.Count(s => s == '/') > n - 1)
            sDir = sDir.Remove(sDir.LastIndexOf('/'));
        return sDir;
    }
```

Comment: Best practice is probably to use regex though. But it all depends on the purpouse :)

Comment: That doesn't remove the characters from the third slash, it removes the characters from the last slash.

Comment: Edited the answer to include something dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Using string operations:

```
str = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf('/', str.IndexOf('/', str.IndexOf('/') + 1) + 1));
```

Using regex:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"^(([^/]*/){2}[^/]*)/.*$", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex is the answer: `^[^/]*\/[^/]*\/[^/]*`. It will capture the first three chunks.

```
var regex = new Regex("^[^/]*\\/[^/]*\\/[^/]*", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var value = regex.Match(str).Value;
```

Comment: What if there's four?

Comment: At first, I did not use any boundaries... Surely no need to add the `$` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way of doing that it's creating a extension

```
     string str = "this/is/an/example";
     str = str.RemoveLastWord();

     //specifying a character
     string str2 = "this.is.an.example";
     str2 = str2.RemoveLastWord(".");
```

With this static class:

```
  public static class StringExtension
 {
   public static string RemoveLastWord(this string value, string separator = "")
   {
     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        return string.Empty;
     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(separator))
        separator = "/";

     var words = value.Split(Char.Parse(separator));

     if (words.Length == 1)
        return value;

     value = string.Join(separator, words.Take(words.Length - 1));

     return value;
  }
}
```